# jQuery .append closes the tag with in the multiline title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I create a HTML dynamically and assign a multiline title to my column header. When I try to append the html to my table, .append closes the tag with in the title attribute.

I read some threads here that I should move the html from .append to a string variable and then append the variable. But that didn't work either.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DP9uc/):

HTML:

```
<table id="tab1">
    <thead>

    </thead>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var title = "Roger A Famz <br/> 213 Wood Ave <br/> Middletown <br/> NY";
var myHtml = "<tr><th>Column 1</th>" +
    "<th id='something' class='someclass' title='" + title + "'>Roger A Famz</th></tr>";

$("#tab1").append(myHtml);
```

If you notice, my title attribute in the rendered html has closed the main  tag:

```
Roger A Famz <br></th> 213 Wood Ave <br/> Middletown <br/> NY
```

instead of

```
Roger A Famz <br/> 213 Wood Ave <br/> Middletown <br/> NY
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you remove the `/` in the `<br/>` it doesn't happen. http://jsfiddle.net/DP9uc/6/

Comment: It works if you add the title via javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/DP9uc/10/

Comment: @Musa, it worked by removing `/`. I thought it works in html5 as Tushar mentioned. How can I mark this as answer? Although, Tushar also recommended the same but you answered before him :)

Comment: @Alex, this is sweet solution too. I tried it and it works as well. I don't know why .append with jquery closes the tag though.

Answer (score 0):

replace `<br/>` with `<br>` in HTML5 you don't need to close br tag

working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/DP9uc/14/

```
var title = "Roger A Famz <br> 213 Wood Ave <br> Middletown <br/> NY";
var myHtml = "<tr><th>Column 1</th>" +
    "<th id='something' class='someclass' title='" + title + "'>Roger A Famz </th></tr>";

$("#tab1").append(myHtml);
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, it works as mentioned by Musa as well. Any how we are not using HTML5 yet.

Comment: modern day browsers render `<br/>` tag as `<br>`